# Entity Framework 6 with an Immutable Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, immutability

I have a `Point` class:

```
// My immutable Point class
public class Point
{
    private readonly Distance _x;
    private readonly Distance _y;
    private readonly Distance _z;

    public Distance X
    {
        get { return _x; }
    }

    public Distance Y
    {
        get { return _x; }
    }

    public Distance Z
    {
        get { return _x; }
    }

    // Ok, so this isn't immutable... but it's purely for EF
    public int DatabaseId { get; set; }

    public Point(Distance x, Distance y, Distance z)
    {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
        _z = z;
    }
}
```

(`Distance` is a custom class that stores a unit and a value.)

That's great. We love immutability. But Entity Framework won't recognize that I need to put X, Y, and Z in the database because they don't have setters. And they shouldn't, because this is an immutable class. There shouldn't even be a `private set`.

I have this code building my model:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Point>()
        .HasKey(point => point.DatabaseId);
```

Is there any way to preserve the true immutability of this class but also make it so that EF6 can access and store these values?

Comment: This might be a bit nitpicky, but shouldn't this be a struct?  And shouldn't you be mapping EF to a mutable class and then using that to create your struct objects?  It seems that you're trying to fit a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: There's no such thing as an immutable database row. If you need an immutable object, you probably need a layer of mapping from the data entity layer to the layer where your immutable type lives.

Comment: Only doable with private setters. But there are more concerns. What should the data model look like? You could have a `Point` table having three FKs to `Distance`, but how would you ensure that three `Distance`s are always referred to by one `Point` (and not by any other `Point`s, I suppose that's what you want).

Answer (score 2):

In a similar situation, I had to create a *private parameterless constructor* that EntityFramework can use and made the `Id` as `private set`. This worked for me fine and it's the best I could do in the time I had in keeping the class immutable.

So in your case, the above class could be updated and simplified as follows:

```
public class Point
{
    public Distance X { get; private set; }
    public Distance Y { get; private set; }
    public Distance Z { get; private set; }
    public int DatabaseId { get; private set; } // DatabaseId can't be set publicly

    private Point() { } // Private Parameterless Constructor for EntityFramework

    public Point(Distance x, Distance y, Distance z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

EF Core 2.0.1:

Model:

```
public class Point
{
    [Obsolete("For ORM(EF) use only", true)]
    public Point() { }

    public Point(Distance x, Distance y, Distance z)
    {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
        _z = z;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Distance X { get => _x; }
    private Distance _x;

    public Distance Y { get => _y; }
    private Distance _y;

    public Distance Z { get => _z; }
    private Distance _z;
}
```

Let EF fill the private fields

```
public class DomainDbContext : DbContext
{      
    /*skipping other stuff you have here*/ 

    public DbSet<Point> Points { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        // Fill Properties with private fields 
        builder.Entity<Point>().Property(m => m.X).UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
        builder.Entity<Point>().Property(m => m.Y).UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
        builder.Entity<Point>().Property(m => m.Z).UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }
}
```

Final issue is using this with a controller so:

```
public class PointViewModel // has default parameterless constructcor
{       
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Distance X { get; set; }

    public Distance Y { get; set; }

    public Distance Z { get; set; }
}
```

Use in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("X,Y,Z")] PointViewModel info)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         var point = new Point(info.X, info.Y, info.Z);

         _context.Add(point);
         await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
         return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
      }
      return View(info);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know EF will store both `_x` and `X` in the table so you must make them public with private setters.

They are still immutable except for the primary key witch EF must be able to set.

Alternatively you can add another layer: the immutable class and the EF table model class and when you pull form the database you get an immutable object while the mutable one will be hidden outside of DAL.